# Алгоритм определения полигона в полигоне

Tags: геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Я нашел простой алгоритм определения нахождения полигона в полигоне суть которого заключается в следующем:

1. Определяются точки пересечения сторон одного полигона со вторым
2. Если точек пересечения нет, то проверяется любая точка первого полигона на принадлежность второму полигону. Если точка принадлежит, то первый полигон полностью находиться во втором полигоне, так как нет пересечений.

У этого алгоритма есть случаи которые показывают неверный результат. В том случае если полигон касается второго полигона, но не пересекает его.

На рисунке видно что все три вершины треугольных полигонов 1 и 2 касаются граней зеленого полигона. Но 1 полностью находиться полигоне, а 2 не принадлежит полигону.
Все три вершины полигонов 1 и 2 находятся в полигоне если считать что вершина принадлежит полигону, если она находиться на его стороне. Поэтому алгоритм определяет что оба треугольника в полигоне.

Точно так же 3 должен быть вне полигона, а 4 принадлежать ему, пересечений нет они просто касаются границ.

как правильно определить принадлежность полигона полигону?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вопрос-то какой?

Comment: *Я нашел простой алгоритм определения нахождения полигона в полигоне суть которого заключается в следующем: Определяются точки пересечения граней одного полигона со вторым* Вы правда считаете поиск пересечения простым? И, к слову - полигоны плоские, у них не может быть граней..

Comment: алгоритм Vatti, реализован, например, в библиотеке Clipper

Comment: Всё звучит правильно, просто где-то надо поменять условие с `>` на `>=`.

Comment: @Kromster, не соглашусь. Тут без варианта Вати или Бентли-Отмана не обойтись. Или за квадрат методом полос. Кстати метод полос можно уложить в ответ. Только будет сложный ответ.

Comment: Согласен. Можно попробовать чуть-чуть модифицировать - *Если точек пересечения нет, то проверяется любая точка **внутри** первого полигона на принадлежность второму полигону.* Но тут тоже немало заморочек получится.